# MSVC claims public member is inaccessible

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a struct like this with a public enum member:

```
namespace A {
    struct Events {
        enum CUES { CLEAR, DATA, ERROR };
        virtual void Event(CUES) = 0;
    protected:
        ~Events() {}
    };
}
```

When I try to access, say, `CLEAR` from another class, the compiler produces an error to say that it is inaccessible.

Here is the code and the error:

```
namespace B {
    class Base: A::Events{
        void Event(Events::CUES){}
    protected:
        Events::CUES lastCue;
    };

    class Impl: public Base {
        bool test(){
            return (lastCue == A::Events::CLEAR);
        }
    };
}

somefile(19): error C2247: 'A::Events::CLEAR' not accessible because 'B::Base' uses 'private' to inherit from 'A::Events'

somefile(3): note: see declaration of 'A::Events::CLEAR'
```

How can I gain access to a public enum?

**Update:**
`gcc` seems to compile this without any trouble.

Comment: You can try class Base : public A::Events

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've come up with is to change the route of access through the global namespace:

```
namespace B {
    class Impl: public Base {
        bool test(){
            return (lastCue == ::A::Events::CLEAR);
        }                   // ^^
    };
}
```

This avoids any changes to `Base`.